# Rock Paper Scissors question - only half return a result

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and was tasked with writing a two-player rock/paper/scissors game using nested if statements. Only half of my outcomes are printing results

The program works with all combinations when I use "else if ("rock".equals(player1) && "paper".equals(player2))" instead of the nested if statements, but having nested ifs is part of the rubric.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Player 1, please choose rock, paper, or scissors: ");
    String player1 = in.next();         
    System.out.print("Player 2, please choose rock, paper, or scissors: ");
    String player2 = in.next(); 

    player1 = player1.toLowerCase();
    player2 = player2.toLowerCase();


    if (player1.equals(player2))
    {
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    }

    else if ("rock".equals(player1))    
    {
        if ("paper".equals(player2))
        {
            System.out.println("Paper covers rock - Player 2 wins!");
        }
    }

    else if ("rock".equals(player1))            
        {
        if ("scissors".equals(player2))     
        {
            System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors - Player 1 wins!");
        }
    }           

    else if ("paper".equals(player1))
    {
        if ("scissors".equals(player2))     
        {
            System.out.println("Scissors cut paper - Player 2 wins!");
        }
    }

    else if ("paper".equals(player1))
    {
        if ("rock".equals(player2))     
        {
            System.out.println("Paper covers rock - Player 1 wins!");
        }
    }       

    else if ("scissors".equals(player1))
    {
        if ("paper".equals(player2))        
        {
            System.out.println("Scissors cut paper - Player 1 wins!");
        }
    }
    else if ("scissors".equals(player1))
    {
        if ("rock".equals(player2))     
        {
            System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors - Player 2 wins!");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again using rock, paper, or scissors");
    }

    in.close();
    }

 }
```

I expected an output for each combination of inputs, but scissors vs rock, rock vs scissors, and paper vs rock don't yield any output to the console.

Comment: You have `else if ("paper".equals(player1))` twice, and it will not be entered into twice, only the first will be entered into.  You need to move the nested `if` under the first  `else if ("paper".equals(player1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else if ("rock".equals(player1))    
{
    if ("paper".equals(player2))
    {
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock - Player 2 wins!");
    }
}
else if ("rock".equals(player1))            
    {
    if ("scissors".equals(player2))     
    {
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors - Player 1 wins!");
    }
}
```

Note that you have the same check twice. When the first one is true, then only that block will execute and the next `else if...` will be skipped. To fix this, just do all of the checks for player2 in one block:

```
else if ("rock".equals(player1))    
{
    if ("paper".equals(player2))
    {
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock - Player 2 wins!");
    }
    else if ("scissors".equals(player2))     
    {
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors - Player 1 wins!");
    }
}
```

You should also learn about the `switch` statement which can provide an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: Although I think a switch would be nicer.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Good point. My suggestion here is using code directly from the OP but suggesting alternatives is good, too.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Totally agree.

Comment: The second assignment for this game covers switch. This one was specifically to use nested ifs.